# Build waveform graph for universal audio source

Tags: .net, xamarin, naudio

I am trying to build a waveform graph for universal audio source using Xamarin + NAudio. First it seemed like WaveViewer is doing what I need to do. So I have ported it to Xamarin. But now it seems to me it's kind of hardcoded to 16 bits WAV files (as it read 2 byte samples independent on file type).

Are there any better samples for that? I looked at WPF sample but didn't found the place where the low-level magic happens yet (I see only glossy WPF controls and bindings for now).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`WaveViewer` is an extremely rudimentary example, and will probably be removed from the main NAudio library.

The strategy for drawing waveforms is usually:

1. Get access to the samples (use NAudio to get an `ISampleProvider` so you can see the samples as floating point)
2. Find the maximum absolute sample value over a short period (e.g. 200ms) and build up a list of peaks
3. In your GUI control, either paint all the peaks as vertical lines onto a scrollable canvas, or for efficiency, every repaint, just draw the peaks that are in view. It depends whether you want to hold the entire WaveForm bitmap in memory or not (may be an issue if you are viewing very long audio files).

I'm afraid I don't have any blog posts on this to point you to, but if you have access to Pluralsight, there is a section on WaveForm drawing in my NAudio course.